How to run two chain that first output is second input using langchain python?
I have two chains
llm = OpenAI()

code_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["task", "language"],
    template="Write a very short {language} function that will {task}."
)
test_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["language", "code"],
    template="Write a unit test for the following {language} code:\n{code}"
)

chain_code: Runnable = code_prompt | llm | {"language": StrOutputParser(), "code": StrOutputParser()}
chain_test: Runnable = test_prompt | llm | {"test": StrOutputParser(), "code": StrOutputParser()}

sequence: Runnable = chain_code | chain_test

result = sequence.invoke({ "task": "return a list of numbers", "language":"python" })

print(">>>>>> GENERATED CODE:")
print(result["code"])

print(">>>>>> GENERATED TEST:")
print(result["test"])

The output of chain_code will be input for chain_test.
The code works but prints same result for code and test. How can I fix this?

There's some documentation for combining chains but it did not feel very intuitive.
I ended up sub classing Runnable and creating a class to handle the chains.
class CombinedChain(Runnable):
    def __init__(self, chain_code, chain_test):
        self.chain_code = chain_code
        self.chain_test = chain_test

    def invoke(self, inputs):
        code_output = self.chain_code.invoke(inputs)["code"]
        test_inputs = {"language": inputs["language"], "code": code_output}
        test_output = self.chain_test.invoke(test_inputs)
        test_output["code"] = code_output
        return test_output

sequence = CombinedChain(chain_code, chain_test)
result = sequence.invoke({ "task": "return a list of numbers", "language":"python" })

